# Check whether two paths point to the same thing using Pathlib, even when target doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

How do I check whether to pathlib.Path's point at the same file system location?

I hoped I could use `.samefile`, but that doesn't work when the files/directories don't exist yet.

Simple `==` also doesn't seem to work: `Path("test/../file")!=Path("file")`

EDIT: Even `Path("test/../file").resolve().absolute()!=Path("file").resolve().absolute()` in general (for example, when I run this on a network drive, the former resolves to `//networkaddress/file` and the latter to `Z:/file`

Comment: I'm not sure there's a sane way to make this work. There's no way to tell that `test/../file` is equivalent to `file` without actually asking the filesystem. For example, if `test` is a symlink, then `test/../file` probably **is not** equivalent to `file`.

Comment: I think you need to compare the content of that file. But it wouldnt be clever for a huge database.

Comment: @larsks good point, though I can make my question well-defined given the context of what I want to use it for: If I first created and wrote to a file, say with `open(a,'w')` and then I wrote to a file using `open(b,'w')`, would I write to the same file twice? What would you do if you wanted to answer this? More specifically, I am sending a job to an external process, telling the external program to write to `a`, and before I do that I want to make sure that I don't already previously sent such a job with the same target, because that would cause the external program to crash/write nonsense.

Comment: I don't know enough of what you're doing to provide an answer. Where are the paths coming from? In what situation do you expect you might receive two paths that look different but actually point to the same file? Will the target files exist before you write to them (e.g., can you just check for their existence before writing)? There are too many questions here to meaningfully answer in the comments, but if you want to update your question to provide a better overview of what you're trying to accomplish that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Since in your case it is only the base name of a given path that may not yet exist, you can normalize the path by resolving the parent instead and then joining back the base name:

```
def normalize_path(path):
    return path.parent.resolve().joinpath(path.name)
```

so that:

```
normalize_path(Path('test/../file')) == normalize_path(Path('file'))
```

returns `True` if `test` exists as a regular directory.

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/HardtofindEquatorialParallelcomputing